# Función js debe interactuar con los datos de un usuario en DJango

Tags: javascript, html, django

Veran, para mi proyecto DJango he creado una función js que tomará como argumento un usuario. Necesito que muestre en un mensaje alert el nombre del usuario.

Codigo HTML:

```
<button style="position:relative; left:35%; top:5px;" onclick="revision({{user}})">Más informacion</button>
```

Codigo JS:

```
function revision(usuario){
alert(usuario.username);
}
```

Sin embargo, la función no me da resultado.
¿Que estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<button style="position:relative; left:35%; top:5px;" onclick="revision('{{user.username}}')">Más informacion</button>
```

Envíale a la función directamente el username, y en la función muéstralo:

```
function revision(name){
    alert(name);
}
```

El problema es que javascript no entiende de Django así que nunca te cogerá sus datos.

Comment: Tambien pasando directamente el username ha fallado. Si pongo una cadena normal en tu funcion si funciona, por lo que es claramente problema de que javascript no capta los datos.

Comment: Cógelo ahora que se me olvidaron las comillas @MiguelAlparez, el problema era que le estaba pasando el nombre de usuario pero no como cadena si no como si fuese una variable

Comment: Ahora si que lo ha hecho.

Comment: Era eso, al javascript le llegaba lo siguiente: `user.name` como objeto y no como string